# How to check impersonation level used in SSAS connection string?

Tags: ssas, windows-authentication, impersonation, olap-cube, windows-users

I set the “Impersonation Level” to four possible values in SSAS connection string and like to test whether it impersonate the windows user.
I made changes in "Data Source Impersonation Info" to “ImpersonateAccount” in SQL Server Management Studio as well
So I logged into another user account in my system, unfortunately I could able to connect with my cube from both the user accounts.
Please help me to achieve impersonation using SSAS connection string.

Example:
string connectionString = @"Data Source=””; Initial Catalog=Adventure Works DW; Provider=SSAS; Impersonation Level=Impersonate";

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Felix Merlin B

Comment: Are you talking of the impersonation of the Data Source object within your Analysis Services database, or of the impersonation of your client tool connection to Analysis Services? These have nothing to do with each other! The first is used when Analysis Services connects to the relational data source to refresh its data (which is called "Processing"), and the second is used when you connect with a client tool to the Analysis Services database, usually in order to read data from the cube.

Comment: I wish to impersonate my client tool connection to Analysis Services.
So I set impersonation Level in the connection string and provided cube access to an user and I logged into another user account to test the impersonation. unfortunately both the users can connect the cube without any authentication.

I'm trying to impersonate the current windows user with "Impersonation Level" in SSAS connection string.